# In Java when one interface extends another, why would one redeclare a method in a subinterface?

Tags: java, interface

I've been looking at the JMS API from J2EE and found a strange behavior where certain methods that are declared in an interface (e.g., createQueue in Session) are declared again in the subinterfaces such as QueueSession, and with identical documentation.

Since an subinterface "inherits" all the method declarations of the interface it inherits, and since the JavaDoc tool has no problem sorting out the JavaDocs of the subinterface and creating an "inherited operations" list, I can't figure out what this achieves.

The only think of is that initially the call was in Session, and then moved to QueueSession when the specific subclass was created, though then I would have expected to see something in the documentation of the upperclass. But this is just conjecture.

So the question is:
Is there a convincing reason to redeclare a method in a subinterface?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having seen this happen on occasion while working for Sun, I can tell you how it usually happens.  Someone defines an interface, let's say Alice, with some methods; many developers implement that interface.

Some time later, it's realized that they need some other interface, call it Bob, that has a subset of the methods of Alice, in order to allow it to serve as a base interface for *another* interface, Clara.

If you move the methods of Alice into Bob, you break all the code that implements Alice; you have to go back and at least recompile a whole bunch of code, some of which you may not own, and for political reasons can't break.

So you don't.

Comment: That makes sense.
But why not change the JavaDocs in the superclass and say something like "Do me a favour, never invoke me directly, instantiate the subinterface"?

Comment: Because that would be admitting a mistake?  More seriously, it might be that the super-"class" interface *is* sometimes used alone; there's no reason a refactoring can't be to simply remove methods.

Comment: "it's realized that they need some other interface, call it Bob, that has a subset of the methods of Alice" If all they need is a subset of Alice, why can't they make Bob a separate interface with only a few methods of Alice, instead of making Alice its superclass?

Comment: Because sometimes inheritance *is* important.  Now a Bob object can be contained in an array of Alice.  Now, sometimes you don't need that, and then you shouldn't do it.  But if you do need that, you have to do it.

Comment: @CharlieMartin - Was still a great company with many great people who were extremely knowledgeable it's a shame it came to an end.

Comment: _If you move the methods of Alice into Bob, you break all the code that implements Alice_  Why is this? since you remove but also you add the `Alice extends Bob`

Comment: @haelix In this example Bob extends Alice. It is a compile time error to then make Alice  extend Bob — The class Graph must be acyclic.

Comment: @CharlieMartin the second paragraph of the answer (_Some time later, it's realized..._) suggests to me that some methods of Alice need to go into Bob and Clara. So it becomes Alice and Clara both extend Bob. (PS just realised you answered this 10y ago, respect!!)

Comment: @haelix The thing is that Alice *can't* extend Bob because Bob already extends Alice. Now, you could *refactor* that whole stack, putting Bob at the top of the graph, and having Alice and Clara extend Bob, but then every application that uses Alice has to be recompiled or refactored to match. With something like JMS where potentially millions of customers have used it, this causes great consternation. So you don't. And thanks btw.

Comment: The explanation doesn’t make the slightest sense. If Bob has a subset of the methods of Alice, why should it be a subtype of Alice, which would end up having *all* of Alice’s method, not just a subset? More importantly, *that doesn’t even explain why Bob redeclares those methods*. Which is what the question was all about. Not about a hypothetical scenario of wrong subtype relationships (do you know any real life example?), but why the subtype redeclares the methods it also inherits.

Comment: @Holger read it again. interface A has methods a,b,c. Now you want an interface B that has b and c, so it can be a base for interface D extends B. You can move a, create B, implement D. But now everyone who used A has to break code to get methods b and c. The issue isn't subtyping, it's temporality — you prefer not to break existing code, especially as the code base exceeds a million SLOC.

Comment: I can’t follow. Is B a subtype of A or A a subtype of B? And why do you say “You can move a” when everything said before is about b and c? It seems you are trying to make everything as complicated as possible, just to hide the nonsensicality in the confusion. *If X is a subtype of Y and Y has a method m, X will have the method m too, without a need to redeclare it*. This never changes, regardless how many curlicues you are making around it.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 5 you can change the return type of a overriding method, by making it more specific.
More commonly the documentation is different so the method has to be declared again.

However if the method and documentation are the same, there is no need for it.  However, you will see plenty of code which isn't strictly needed.  It is possible it was needed once, but something was changed so it is no longer needed.  It is quite likely that it was never needed but was done because the developer thought something needed to be done when actually there wasn't a good basis for it.

BTW: Different people have different views of what is needed or handy to have or better to make explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a good reasoning for this.  The best I have seen is that:

- It makes it clear what it is without having to see the parent
- It makes it easier to change what the class extends without having to figure out what interfaces it should implement

I don't like either suggestion.  I think the likely cause is that while the code was being written the interfaces were written before the abstract classes and the developers didn't bother to remove the duplicate implements.

Never underestimate the laziness of a developer :-)

In the end no harm is done except that at class load time it probably takes a non-noticeable fraction of time longer to load a class with duplicate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, there is no reason to do this.  I can imagine a couple ways this could happen during the evolution of some code though.  It's not uncommon to take an existing interface and pull a smaller super-interface out of it.  In that circumstance, I can imagine leaving the existing interface but just changing it to extend from a new interface.

Answer (score -1):

the only reason i know of is to widen the visibility of a method (i.e. clone from protected to public), but that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: That's not possible with an interface.  The visibility of a method is defined by the visibility of the interface itself.  And you are not allowed to reduce visibility in a sub-interface.

Comment: Also, Cloneable does not have any methods