# Why does NavigableSet (which extends SortedSet) declare subSet(E fromElement, E toElement) again?

Tags: java

The `interface NavigableSet<E>` extends `interface SortedSet<E>` which declares the method
`SortedSet<E>   subSet(E fromElement, E toElement)` . 
However, when I look at [NavigableSet's API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), I see that it has declared the same method (with exactly the same signature). I also see that it says it inherits some methods (first, last, comparable) from [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Since by definition, interfaces only contain method signatures, why would any child interface redeclare the same method that the parent interface has already declared (and there's no difference in semantics, in the API javadoc)?

Edit: Came across a relevant and nice discussion here -
 [In Java when one interface extends another, why would one redeclare a method in a subinterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563952/in-java-when-one-interface-extends-another-why-would-one-redeclare-a-method-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing so is certainly *allowed* in Java.

Here is the source code:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * Equivalent to {@code subSet(fromElement, true, toElement, false)}.
 */
public SortedSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, E toElement)
```

Perhaps the author of the class found it worthwhile to repeat the definition because there is a *second* definition of `subSet` that returns a `NavigableSet`, so having both show up side-by-side in the Javadoc listing was nicer than having one in the main method listing and one in the "inherited" section.

There was surely no good reason to do this for `first` and `last`, so this was not done.

Here is the rationale from the Javadocs for adding the second versions of subSet, headSet, and tailSet:

> Methods subSet(E, E), headSet(E), and tailSet(E) are specified to return SortedSet to allow existing implementations of SortedSet to be compatibly retrofitted to implement NavigableSet, but extensions and implementations of this interface are encouraged to override these methods to return NavigableSet.

You might wish to try your own experiment, designing a couple of interfaces, one inheriting from another, with the subinterface adding a new version of an inherited method, to see if the respecification was necessary. :-)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! I knew that it is allowed in java; just didn't understand why anyone would do that. Now I do.

Comment: You can redeclare methods in subinterfaces if you want to add something to their Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet%28E,%20E%29) for `NavigableSet.subSet()`, it says

Specified by: `subSet in interface SortedSet<E>`.

Now, the meaning of "specified by" in Javadoc is revealed, for example, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/whatsnew-1.3.html):

> The "Specified by:" link has been added for a method in an interface
>   implementing a method from a superinterface.

So this method, just like you expect, is actually only declared in `SortedSet` :)

Comment: No, I had a look at NavigableSet's code and it does re-declare SortedSet. "specified by" is used to mean that the super-interface has specified it as well