# Map and SortedMap - redundant methods declaration

Tags: oop, collections, dictionary, java

When inspecting `Map` and `SortedMap` interfaces, I have noticed many methods that are already defined within `Map` interface are also redefined (not simply let inherited) within the `SortedMap`.

`SortedMap` extending `Map`, why redeclaring some methods like for instance:

```
Set<K> keySet();
Collection<V> values();
```

Why this redundancy?

(I use JDK 7)

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung Thanks, someone in the linked post said: "They redeclared them just for the sake of convenience. Also it helps to redefine the javadocs of that particular method". It suits me :)

Comment: This is the right link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13205286/738746.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that methods are declared in interfaces and methods are defined in classes.

Map are not guaranteed to be ordered but Sorted Maps are.  This means what each method will guarantee is different and needs different documentation.

The Javadoc for [Map.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) is **highlighting the differences**

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.
>
> Returns:
>      a set view of the keys contained in this map

The Javadoc for [SortedMap.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet%28%29) is

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. **The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order.** The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.
>
> Specified by:
>       keySet in interface Map
>
> Returns:
>       a set view of the keys contained in this map, **sorted in ascending order**