# Java Collection And Set Interface Design Question?

Tags: java, collections, set

`java.util.Collection` interface has method `size()`, `isEmpty()`, `contains(Object o)` etc, Why the sub interface `java.util.Set` redefine the method `size()`, `isEmpty()`, `contains(Object o)`. is this Override？But Doug Lea's collection framework `Set` interface not redefine the `Collection` method. Why? What is different? [image]

Comment: Try going through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html#:~:text=A%20Set%20is%20a%20Collection%20that%20cannot%20contain%20duplicate%20elements.&text=Two%20Set%20instances%20are%20equal,HashSet%20%2C%20TreeSet%20%2C%20and%20LinkedHashSet%20.

Comment: The sub interface does not redefine the methods (since it also gives no implementation). A reason why they actually put the method declarations there, is so that they can overwrite the JavaDoc comments for Set specifix comments.

Comment: You may want to read this: [In Java when one interface extends another, why would one redeclare a method in a subinterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563952/in-java-when-one-interface-extends-another-why-would-one-redeclare-a-method-in)

Comment: @Gtomika  maybe they're at different levels of abstraction，but why doug lea set not put method declaration there？

Comment: @LiLi I was looking at this OpenJDK source file: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Set.java.html

Comment: Did you read and understood this notice of Doug Lea: “*While there are some design and implementation differences, the JDK1.2 package contains most of the same basic abstractions, structure, and functionality as this package. For this reason, this collections package will NOT be further updated*”?